# How to add properties to an object

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I am doing an images gallery in JavaScript and I have a problem adding properties to my `img` object.

Here is my code:

```
img_big.src = photos[i].img_src;
img_big.className = "highslide";
img_big.onclick = "return hs.expand(this)";
```

My problem is in the last line. How can I add properties to objects in a `for` loop before pushing them into an array?

The object should has these properties:

```
<a href="path" class="highslide" onclick="return hs.expand(this)"> 
<img src="path" alt="Highslide JS" title="Click to enlarge" /></a>
```

Comment: Is `this` supposed to be `img_big`?

Comment: *What* is your problem? That `.onclick` expects a function, not a string? Are you getting an exception, does something not work as intended?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this approach

```
img_big.src = photos[i].img_src;
img_big.className = "highslide";
img_big.onclick = function() { return hs.expand(this); }
```

Comment: Naw, sometimes, we need the perspective of another eye, to see our errors.